# Skip Holidays in Business day Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-scripts

I am using the following script to determine what the business days are for each particular month.

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME
SET @startdate ='20170401'
;
WITH bd AS(
SELECT
DATEADD(DAY,
CASE
    (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @startdate), 0)) + @@DATEFIRST - 1) % 7
    WHEN 6 THEN 2
    WHEN 7 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END,
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @startdate), 0)
) AS bd, 1 AS n
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,
CASE
    (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, bd.bd) + @@DATEFIRST - 1) % 7
    WHEN 5 THEN 3
    WHEN 6 THEN 2
    ELSE 1
END,
bd.bd
) AS db,
bd.n+1
FROM bd WHERE MONTH(bd.bd) = MONTH(@startdate)
)
SELECT * INTO #BD
FROM (
SELECT 'BD'+ CAST(n AS VARCHAR(5)) AS Expected_Date_Rule, bd AS Expected_Calendar_Date
from bd
) AS x
```

The result of this table works fine. Bd is the the calendar days for the particular month and n is the business day number. The script does its job of not counting the weekend as a business day.

```
bd                      n
----------------------- -----------
2017-04-03 00:00:00.000 1
2017-04-04 00:00:00.000 2
2017-04-05 00:00:00.000 3
2017-04-06 00:00:00.000 4
2017-04-07 00:00:00.000 5
2017-04-10 00:00:00.000 6
2017-04-11 00:00:00.000 7
2017-04-12 00:00:00.000 8
2017-04-13 00:00:00.000 9
2017-04-14 00:00:00.000 10
2017-04-17 00:00:00.000 11
2017-04-18 00:00:00.000 12
2017-04-19 00:00:00.000 13
2017-04-20 00:00:00.000 14
2017-04-21 00:00:00.000 15
2017-04-24 00:00:00.000 16
2017-04-25 00:00:00.000 17
2017-04-26 00:00:00.000 18
2017-04-27 00:00:00.000 19
2017-04-28 00:00:00.000 20
2017-05-01 00:00:00.000 21
```

But then I notice that a potential issue will occur in July where the output will count the 4th of July as BD2 when it should be counted as BD3.  Some had created a holiday table that is updated with all the holidays (excuse the bad spelling).

```
Holiday table
 
1              2017-01-01          New Year Day
4              2017-01-02          New Year Day-Follow
1              2017-01-16          MArtin Luther King Day
4              2017-01-17          MArtin Luther King Day-Follow
1              2017-02-20          Preseiednt Day
4              2017-02-21          Preseiednt Day-Follow
1              2017-05-29          Memorial Day
4              2017-05-30          Memorial Day-Follow
1              2017-07-04          Independence Day
4              2017-07-05          Independence Day-Follow
1              2017-09-04          Labour Day
4              2017-09-05          Labour Day-Follow
1              2017-10-09          Columbus Day
4              2017-10-10          Columbus Day-Follow
1              2017-11-10          Vetrans Day
4              2017-11-11          Vetrans Day-Follow
1              2017-11-23          ThanksGiving
1              2017-11-24          Day After Thanks Giving
4              2017-11-24          ThanksGiving-Follow
4              2017-11-25          Day After Thanks Giving-Follow
1              2017-12-25          Christmas
4              2017-12-26          Christmas-Follow
```

I was thinking there may be some way I can update my script to check the holiday table and skip the holiday and dont count it as a business day.  Any tips?

Comment: You can join to the holiday table and then drop records which match to a holiday.

Comment: i think you should use "not exists (select  1 from holidaytable h where h.date=bd.bd )" in last